# Sidekiq and unqueueing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am currently enabling queueing in on of my app wrote in Ruby. I use sidekiq and have define a worker class as below:

```
class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(params)
    sleep 10
    @@logger.info("--------------------------")
    @@logger.info("Request received")
    @@logger.info("--------------------------")
  end
end
```

I am calling it from my main entry point called 'api.rb'

```
post '/receive/?' do
  @@logger.debug("/retrieve endpoint received")
  Worker.perform_async @params
end
```

this working fine and each time the sleep is done, the next queued task is started.

In my case, I need to unqueued or start the next item queued only when I decide it. it will be triggered by an external event.

in my 'api.rb', I have added:

```
post '/response/?' do
    next_task
end
```

The way the code works is that '/receive' can queued 10 requests. the first request will triggered a specific action (sent a post command to a server).

I expect the remote server to send me back a request through '/response' to tell me that the action is finished. when this response is received, I use the 'next_task' api to remove the previous task which was running and now completed and move to the next queued one.

Any idea, how to create a custom trigger to unqueue and start the new job. Is there SIGNAL which allow me to avoid the sidekiq framework to unqueue until I send a specific signal.

Merci

Answer (score 0):

To delete a job in a Sidekiq queue, you would have to iterate the whole queue. It is not an idiomatic use of the queue.

I am afraid I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do. Just remember that you can store state outside of the Sidekiq queue, for example you can have a model for the Job:

```
post '/receive/?' do
  job = Job.create(@params)
  Worker.perform_in(10.seconds)
end
```

and then in the worker:

```
def perform
  job = Job.find_oldest_unexecuted      
  if job
    job.execute!
  else
    # wait another 10 seconds
    Worker.perform_in(10.seconds)
  end
end
```

And in Job:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_oldest_unexecuted
    where(executed_at: nil).order(:id).first
  end
  def execute!
    # do what needs to be done here
    update_attribute(:executed_at, Time.zone.now)
  end
end
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is to control the start of the next job. By default, a queue is automatically starting a new job when the previous is finished. In my case, I need to start the next job only when I ask for because the job is done on a remote server and I can't really control when the remote task is over.

Comment: Yes, that's what i wrote. Use the sidekiq queue just as a 'wake-up-event', every 10s and store the real queue in the database - in a model `Job` in my example.